# $P(\mu \in (\bar{X} - 1/2, \bar{X} + 1/2))$ for Gauss distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

Let $\bar{X}$ be the mean of a random sample of size $n$ from $N(\mu=u, \sigma^2 = 10)$ Find $n$ so that the probability is a approximately $0.954$ that the random interval $(\bar{X} - 1/2, \bar{X} + 1/2)$ includes $\mu$.

I began with $P(\bar{X} - 1/2 < u < \bar{X} + 1/2) = 0.954$ then I'm not sure as to where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some hints:**

- $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_i$ with (most probably you forgot to mention) $X_i \stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim}N(u,10)$
- $\Rightarrow \bar X \sim N(u,10/n)$
- $\Rightarrow Z = \frac{\bar X - u}{\sqrt{10/n}} \sim N(0,1)$
- $\bar X -  \frac{1}{2} < u < \bar X +  \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow |\bar X - u | < \frac{1}{2}$
- $P(|\bar X - u |< \frac{1}{2})  \Leftrightarrow P(|Z| < \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{10}})$
- $P(|Z| < 2) \approx 0.9545$
- $\Rightarrow 2 = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{10}}$

Comment: Do you use Student t-distribution or Gauss distribution?

Comment: @LadaDudnikova : Since the variance is known and does not have to be estimated from  the sample, we only have a Gauss distribution (normal distribution). t-distribution comes into play, if you need to estimate the variance from the sample.

Comment: $P(|Z|<1.69)$ is much nearer to $0.9545$, can I better the estimate substituting 2 by 1.69?

Comment: @LadaDudnikova : Are you sure about your result? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P%28%7CZ%7C%3C2%29%2C+Z%7EN%280%2C1%29

Comment: I used table for one-sided probability, mea culpa

Comment: @LadaDudnikova : Just a side note: There is a thumb rule for normal distributions: 1-2-3 $\sigma$ around the mean correspond to $68\% - 95.5\% - 99.7\%$.